# C Replace a string from a 2d char array using strcpy Issue

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, strcpy

Why does it print out the new word minus the first character when i `printf("%s\n",array[0])` and not `"Hello"`. Any tips for how to do solve that ?
Thanks in advance !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char newword;
  char array[100][20]={
    {'H','e','l','l','o'},
    {'W','o','r','l','d'},
 };
    printf("%s\n",array[0]);
    printf("%s\n",array[1]);

    printf("Type a new word: ");
    scanf("%s",&newword);

    strcpy(array[1],&newword);
    printf("%s\n",array[0]);
    printf("%s\n",array[1]);

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This statement scanf("%s",&newword); overwrites the memory beyond the character object newword.

Comment: @4386427 No it is there (by accident?), just sneakily hidden.

Comment: @4386427 You have a point though, that it would be much better to write `{'H','e','l','l','o', '\0'},` as self-documenting code, demonstrating to the reader that "yes indeed I know what I'm doing". Or well... just write `"Hello"`...

Comment: @Lundin agree ... but still my comment was incorrect so I removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course `newword` is not capable of holding a string (except the empty string) since it's just a single character, not an array. Using that with `scanf()` like you do is undefined behavior.

Make it:

```
char newword[20];
```

for instance, and preferably also `scanf(" %19s", newword);`, and check that `scanf()` succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `char newword; ... scanf("%s",&newword)` yields undefined behaviour; you read in a string into a variable holding a single character; From that point on, all bets are off.

Write `char newword[100]; ...` and things should do better.